# "unrecognized .svn/entries format" using buildout

Tags: python, svn, setuptools, buildout, distribute

Since upgrading to subversion 1.7 I get "unrecognized .svn/entries format" when running buildout.  I notice there is an unresolved bug reports for both distribute and setuptools for this error and it also seems that you can use [setuptools_subversion](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_subversion) to resolve the issue.

What I can't find out how to do is install setuptools_subversion so that buildout picks it up.  Please can  someone help?

I've tried

- downloading it and running python setup.py install
- adding it to the eggs list of the [buildout] part of my buildout configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install it at the python site-packages level; easy_install (used under the hood by buildout) needs it available before it'll install anything else.

That said, the `python setup.py install` stanza should have installed it just fine; check by running the following test:

```bash
$ python -m setuptools_subversion
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools_subversion.py directory
```

That should print the installation path of the module, like it did for me in the above example. You could try to use pip or easy_install for automatic download:

```bash
$ pip install setuptools_subversion
```

or

```bash
$ easy_install setuptools_subversion
```

You can do that in a virtualenv if you want to isolate the installation. Because this is basically a dependency for svn 1.7, installing this at the same level as the svn binary (usually system wide) is certainly acceptable and the norm.

Note that the `unrecognized .svn/entries format` error message will *not* disappear, but your buildout will otherwise succeed. The message is printed no matter what as easy_install first tries the internal `.svn` parser before deferring to the external plugin.

If you really, really want to verify if the plugin is installed, run the following python code:

```py
import pkg_resources
for entrypoint in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('setuptools.file_finders'):
    print entrypoint
```

On my system this prints:

```
svn = setuptools_subversion:listfiles
svn_cvs = setuptools.command.sdist:_default_revctrl
git = setuptools_git:gitlsfiles
hg = setuptools_hg:hg_file_finder
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn.  It turns out it was installed - I was getting confused because the `unrecognized .svn/entries format` was still appearing and because when trying to build a revision egg I was getting -r0.  I guess that's for another issue though

Comment: Once you have install `setuptools_subversion` you need to manually remove the original `setuptools` installation from the `setuptools.pth` or `easy install.pth` file.

Comment: @sakra: `setuptools_subversion` is **not** a replacement! You *not* remove `setuptools` itself.

Comment: @sakra: `setuptools_subversion` is a *plugin* for `setuptools`. You need *both*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So to use `setuptools_subversion` you just have to install it, nothing more to configure?

Comment: @Joril: yes, because installing it [registers an entry point](https://github.com/mjpieters/setuptools_subversion/blob/master/setup.py#L35-L38); `setuptools` looks for that entry point.